# Repeat call to React Component every 60 seconds to automatically refresh front end display

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scheduled-tasks

I have a React component that fetches data from a url fed by a Flask backend and displays a line graph using that data. I want to refresh the graph on the front end without the user having to manually refresh the page.

The code is:

```
function Graph() {
  const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGraphData();
  }, []);
  
  const fetchGraphData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("url")
    const fetchedGraphData = await result.json();

    if(res.ok) {
      setGraphData(fetchedGraphData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <LineChart>
        ....
        </LineChart>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` everywhere and any way I could think of but I can't get it to work at all.

I've gather that `setTimeout` should be better because it would be guaranteed to wait for a server response before executing again, as opposed to `setInterval` which could queue up queries in case of delays.

Comment: It looks like you could just re-call `fetchGraphData()` after x amount of time? Where exactly did you try those timer methods?

Comment: @DBS, I just put it in another `useEffect` hook and it seems to work. Do you think it's better to put it in the `useEffect` I already have? Right now, after the one I already had, I added `useEffect(() => { const intervalCall = setInterval(() => {fetchGraphdata();}, 60000); return () => {clearInterval(intervalCall);};});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need a timer to achieve that goal.

In your `useEffect` try writing this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
   fetchGraphData();
  },60*1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

In return all is just a cleanup function to ensure there is no timer running after unmounting the component.
To know more about cleanup function https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: Thank you, do you think it's better to write this code in the already existing `useEffect()` or create a separate `useEffect()` just for the `setInterval` piece of code?

Comment: You can,  but no need to write two separate useEffect that has same dependency.  If you have different dependency then you can create as many useEffect you need. You can read more about useEffect hooks here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html